# Local relative images are not loading in WebView. UWP Windows 10

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

When I am trying to Load an html using NavigateToString stored in LocalStorage folder of Windows 10 application. It is not loading its relative files like CSS, Javascript, Images.

I have used base tag on the top as well. Same concept works for Silverlight application.

Comment: Can you please post the code of your local html?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to Load an html using NavigateToString stored in LocalStorage folder of Windows 10 application

Firstly, I don't know if these relative files are included in your app(as Content), you need to ensure that.

And if you need to modify the reference links to fit your local resource, consider using [NavigateToLocalStreamUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetolocalstreamuri.aspx) and an implementation of the [IUriToStreamResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.web.iuritostreamresolver.aspx) interface, they can help us to custom loading of HTML and support files (such as CSS, script, and images). Check this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/5a304994b1196958546b20d1fd9746faabbdce39/Samples/XamlWebView)

I just did a simple test based on this [WinRT 8.1 sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Store-Apps-How-to-8073b0da#content)(easy to convert to UWP app)

I could embed local images correctly if I included them as **Content** in the app

[image]

Comment: Thanks Franklin, let me check the approach and I will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Franklin, Now I can open the images. But the problem is my HTML are encrypted and I cannot store decrypted HTML to LocalStorage because of security purpose.
HTML files I have to navigateToString only. How can I solve this issue. Any help?

Comment: @user3678684 I would suggest you decrypt your html file and save into ApplicationData.TemporaryFolder and clear it when app goes to inactivate status, could you please open a new question for this new issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that UWP WebView has troubles with quotes ' ' in JS files.

In my example i had:

```
element.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image.src + ')'
```

All browsers show image without issues, but not WebView.
So I change quotes like this:

```
element.style.backgroundImage = "url(\'" + image.src.toString() + "\')"
```

And it worked! Hope this will solve your issue.